# Are bash function variables parallel-safe when backgrounded?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, shared-memory

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo {
   bar=$(cmd_1 $1)
   baz=$(cmd_2 $1)
   combine_results $bar $baz
}

for arg in $(get_arg_list);
do
   foo &
done
```

Can the multiple instances of `bar` and `baz` clobber each other when `foo &` is run many times? Or are these variables local to each instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are bash function variables parallel-safe when backgrounded?

Yes.

> Can the multiple instances of bar and baz clobber each other when foo & is run many times?

No. (Assuming that `cmd_1` and `cmd_2` and `combine_results` are themselves "parallel-safe" to execute, as in they will not output a "clobbered" result). All the `foo` processes write to the same output - the output may be interleaved (but not "clobbered", as in "invalid" or some indeterminate output).

> Or are these variables local to each instance?

Yes. (Local, as in, local to the process. The variables are global, ie. `( foo ; echo $bar ) &` will print the value of `bar` set inside the function).

Each subshell is a separate process with its own process space and separate [execution environment](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12).

Your variable expansions are not quoted. The `for i in $(...)` is a common **anti**pattern. Note that you are *not* pasing any arguments to your function - `$1` is unset and expands to nothing. Check your scripts with shellcheck.net .